# Inserindo cadastro no bando de dados - erro

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, estou com um erro na hora de cadastrar alguns dados no meu banco de dados. Segue uma parte do código e o erro que aparece.

```
include_once("settings.php");
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS);
        $query = "SELECT bd_winfo FROM cadastro WHERE login = '".$login."'";
        $cadastrar = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, data, cpf, email, pais, estado, login, senha, rsenha)
                      VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$data', '$cpf', '$email', '$pais', '$estado', '$login', '$senha', '$rsenha')";
                if(mysqli_query($cadastrar, $con))
                {
                    $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
                    $_SESSION['sobrenome'] = $sobrenome;
                    $_SESSION['data'] = $data;
                    $_SESSION['cpf'] = $cpf;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['pais'] = $pais;
                    $_SESSION['estado'] = $estado;
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
                    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;    
                    $_SESSION['rsenha'] = $rsenha;                  


                    header('Location: cadastroRealizado.php');




                }
```

EDIT: A parte do erro é na linha:  if(mysqli_query($cadastrar, $con))
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo, mas agora não esta fazendo o cadastro no banco de dados, da erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você se esqueceu de passar a conexão antes da query.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","marcelo","9090","banco_de_dados");
$query = "SELECT * from users";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você inverteu os parâmetros do `mysqli_query`.

O correto seria `mysqli_query($con,$cadastrar)`